# Бот не видит мои эмодзи в dm канале discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content.startswith("!reg"):
        eb_reg = discord.Embed(title="Wanna register ?", color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        reg_msg = await msg.author.send(embed=eb_reg)
        await reg_msg.add_reaction(emoji="")
        await reg_msg.add_reaction(emoji="")


        def filter(reaction, user):
            return str(reaction.emoji) == "" and user != client.user


        try:
            await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120, check=filter)

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await msg.channel.send('out of time')
        else:
            await msg.channel.send('got it')
```

Вот пример кода. Цель была в том, чтобы пользователь реагировал на сообщения бота с помощь эмодзи, которые бот добавляет на свои сообщения, однако по какой то причине мои эмодзи он не видит, однако если убрать проверку автора эмодзи, реагирует на собственные. Все нужные `Insist`ы даны. Также пробовал `on_reaction_add` и `on_raw_reaction_add`, результат был тот же самый.

Answer (score 0):

Запустил тот же код, что и у вас - у меня все работает. Правда, я дописал пару строк и изменил структуру кода на более правильную.

Команды с префиксом нужно реализовывать не через `if msg.content.startswith("!reg")`, а через отдельную функцию.

Но в любом случае, ваша версия кода тоже работает. Попробуйте этот код, если не поможет, я попробую разобраться и дополню ответ.

**Не забудьте указать токен!**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.command()
async def reg(ctx):
    eb_reg = discord.Embed(title="Wanna register?", color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
    try:
        reg_msg = await ctx.message.author.send(embed=eb_reg)
    except:
        print('The author has banned private messages')
    await reg_msg.add_reaction(emoji="")
    await reg_msg.add_reaction(emoji="")
    
    def filter(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction.emoji) == "" and user != client.user


    try:
        await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120, check=filter)

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('out of time')
    else:
        await ctx.send('got it')

client.run('token')
```